# how to deal with duplicate ajax request generated by page refresh during long polling

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

Now I met with a problem with using long polling, my situation is:

1. The client will send ajax request to server for latest application
   data, the data is required to update web page.
2. We don't know when the data will change, so we can either choose to ask server periodically( traditional http polling ) or long
   polling. I used long polling to save resources.
3. If an user visit the page, the request is sent to server immediately. And on the server side, it is hold until an event
   happen, then the data is returned.
4. I am using java servlets on server side.

**The problem is:**

Suppose if a request from client A is under processing. There are two bad cases:

1. The client refresh the page, then a new ajax request will be sent to the server. The the server might need to process many useless duplicate requests
2. Then the client closed the page because of some
   reasons. How should I know the client has left and how to deal with
   the request.

How can I deal with these cases, the prevention is on the client side or server side.

Comment: i guess your both points are harmless you dont need to worry about those. nobody is as free to refresh pages all the day, and if client left the page then AJAX call will fail nothing more than that :)

Comment: Thanks first..Yes,I don't care whether the call failed or not .. The reason why I worry is that to process a request requires to keep checking into system which consumes server load. And the process won't die until update event happens.

Comment: then in that case we usually ran a low priority Thread for cleaning which will take care of all died process.

Comment: Oh I solved this by using a timeout so at least after some time the request will be handle no matter the client is connected or not. Anyway, thank you!